# Setting maximum number of iterations in CVX (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, cvx

How can I set (and see the default) maximum number of iteration in CVX? I want to set a smaller number of iterations to make my algorithm faster. 
Also is there any way I can set the convergence threshold?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To set number of iteration of solver use `cvx_slvitr` instruction and for convergence threshold, I think, setting the tolerance level achieved by the solver with `cvx_slvtol` would work.
For more details refer to CVX manual at:

http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/solver.html

Comment: Hello, I try to write something like cvx_slvitr = 2000 for example but the solver seems to ignore the max number of iterations I set. Isn't it this that you propose?